# JSON Schema modify

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, npm, jsonschema

While developing a MEAN stack application when I am posting some data from angularJS, a JSON is getting created. I want to convert it to a custom JSON with key in double quotes and numeric value without quotes.
For example,

Generated Schema:
{ id: 'aa',
  cmd: 'ls',
  cpu: '1.15',
  mem: '15',
  executor: '1',
  instances: '1' }

Desired Schema:
{ "id": "aa",
  "cmd": "ls",
  "cpu": 1.15,
  **"mem": 15,**
  "executor": "1",
  **"instances": 1** }

Is there any way or any npm module which convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function parseNumber(obj){
 for (var key in obj) {
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         if(isNaN(obj[key])) {
   if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    parseNumber(obj[key]);
   }
   }
   else {
   obj[key] = parseFloat(obj[key]);
   }
       }
    }
    return obj;
}
var obj = { id: 'aa', cmd: 'ls', cpu: '1.15', mem: '15', executor: '1', instances: '1' };
console.log(JSON.stringify(parseNumber(obj)));
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json

Comment: This will add the double quotes to both key and value on every field in the object.
My requirement is to add double quotes to only string not on the number fields.

Comment: It will not put double quotes on every object. It will add double quotes which are string. May be your number is as string type. If so, you can parse it and change the number as number type with parseFloat() and parseInt() wherever applicable. 
Note:  typeof '1' is string while type of 1 is number